# Flask with JSONRPC with HTTPS server with non-verifiable cert

Tags: python, flask

I am following the example [here](https://github.com/cenobites/flask-jsonrpc/wiki/Examples) showing how to do JSON RPC calls with Flask.  And I have everything working with HTTP server, but I want to use HTTPS server.  I also want to use a cert/key that are not from a trusted source, they are my own.  In some parts of the code I use `requests` and I can set `verify=False`, and those requests work.

But I can't seem to find the way to turn off verification with `from flask_jsonrpc.proxy import ServiceProxy`.

The client code looks like this,

```
from flask_jsonrpc.proxy import ServiceProxy

proxy = ServiceProxy('https://127.0.0.1:6600/api')
r = proxy.Test.ping(username='name', password='password')
```

The exact code above works if I use HTTP (ie change the server to HTTP).  Looking thru some of the `ServiceProxy` code I didn't see a way of setting `verify=False` to anything...  Or maybe there is a way to change the `headers` used by `ServiceProxy` to achieve the setting?

The error that I get is,
`<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)>`, which is what I get from `requests` unless I set `verify=False` (which I do and they work).

More Background:

1) In this setup, the clients and servers are on an isolated network, not on the internet.  What I thought I could get for "free" with using HTTPS endpoints is encryption of the packets between these servers/clients.  Because these computers are not on the internet, I didn't think the certs could be externally verified, and/or I didn't want the certs to expire in a year or two.

2) In this setup Flask server is used to run the client and servers "in production".  I know this is not recommended.

3) The Flask app is started like this,

```
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=6600, debug=False, ssl_context=('cert.pem', 'key.pem'))
```

4) The certs are generated from,

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365
```

Comment: HTTPS should be implemeneted with a reverse proxy like `nginx`.  At a glance of the json_rpc docs you linked, `ServiceProxy` is a class used for testing, so you *should* be hitting your **non-https** endpoints with this.  Also setting `verify=False` on requests just ignores the certs outright, which at worse is a security problem, at best an indicator of bad application architecture.  This question is hard to give advice on without more info on how your SSL is confgirued, and of course more code.

Comment: Thank you.  More background provided.  Based on looking into the `ServiceProxy` code, I don't see the `verify` exposed, so that seems like a dead end.